# Node.js error : throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Tags: node.js

I am getting following error while making the request:

throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
here is my code:
    let event_hub2 = fabric_client.newEventHub();
            event_hub2.setPeerAddr('grpc://localhost:7053');

```
            event_hub2.connect();
            event_hub2.registerBlockEvent(
                (block) => {
                  var first_tx = block.data.data[0]; // get the first transaction
                  var header = first_tx.payload.header; // the "header" object contains metadata of the transaction
                  var channel_id = header.channel_header.channel_id;
                  if ("mychannel" !== channel_id) return;
                      console.log('#####inside block listener######');
                      //console.log(JSON.stringify(block));
                     //res.send(block);

                       //res.end(JSON.stringify(block));
                    // res.json(JSON.parse(block.toString()));
                return  res.send({
        'number':block.header.number.toString(),
        'previous_hash':block.header.previous_hash,
        'data_hash':block.header.data_hash,
        'transactions':block.data.data
    })
                  // do useful processing of the block
                },
                (err) => {
                  console.log('Oh snap!');
                },
             {startBlock:23, endBlock:30, unregister: true, disconnect: true}
              );

    }).catch((err) => {
         console.error('Failed to invoke chain :: ' + err);
    });
```

Comment: can you upload entire code?

Comment: Not enough code here for us to see enough context to know where you're sending double responses to the same requeset.

Answer (score 0):

This happens all the time when you use nodejs because some asynchronous function gets called after the response is sent. It doesn't matter what your code does. Use the debugger.

Start your process with the `--inspect` argument and attach your debugger.

See this reference for help: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/

You will need to connect your chrome browser to the host running the node process.

I suggest you carefully step through your code until you find the problem. Put breakpoints at the places where headers are set and trap your error. Good luck.

Comment: While I see you're trying to be helpful, this doesn't really answer the question.  It's debugging advice.

Comment: Thanks alot .I have debugged and found the problem was with my event listener.Resolved it by using socket communication.

Answer (score 0):

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent, means that you're already in the body or finished state, but some function tried to set a header or status code. Check your code that tries to send a header after some of the body has already been written or the header has already been sent.